# Conscientious print to stdout from Python daemon

Tags: python, python-daemon

I wrote a simple script using [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) which prints to `sys.stdout`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import daemon
import sys
import time


def main():
    with daemon.DaemonContext(stdout=sys.stdout):
        while True:
            print "matt daemon!!"
            time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script works as I would hope, except for one major flaw--it interrupts my input when I'm typing in my shell:

```
(daemon)modocache $ git clomatt daemon!!
matt daemon!!ne
matt daemon!! https://github.com/schacon/cowsay.git
(daemon)modocache $
```

Is there any way for the output to be displayed in a non-intrusive way? I'm hoping for something like:

```
(daemon)modocache $ git clo
matt daemon!! # <- displayed on new line
(daemon)modocache $ git clo # <- what I had typed so far is displayed on a new line
```

Please excuse me if this is a silly question, I'm not too familiar with how shells work in general.

#### Edit: Clarification

The reason I would like this script to run daemonized is that I want to provide updates to the shell user from within the shell, such as printing weather updates to the console in a non-intrusive way. If there is a better way to accomplish this, please let me know. But the purpose is to display information from within the terminal (not via, say, Growl notifications), without blocking.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be an "instant" notification, and you can wait until the next time the user runs a command, you can bake all kinds of things into your `bash` shell prompt. Mine tells me the time and the `git` repository status for the directory I'm in, for example.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I should have thought of that. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it? It would help if you could include a link with more information on how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be an "instant" notification, and you can wait until the next time the user runs a command, you can bake all kinds of things into your `bash` shell prompt. Mine tells me the time and the git repository status for the directory I'm in, for example.

The shell variable for "normal user" shell prompts is `PS1`, so Googling for `bash PS1` or `bash prompt customisation` will get you some interesting examples.

Here's some links:

- [Some basic customisations](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/)
- A more complex example: [`git bash` prompt](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/01/colorful-bash-prompt-reflecting-git-status/)

In general, you can include the output of any arbitrary script in the prompt string. Be aware, however, that high-latency commands will delay printing of the prompt string until they can be evaluated, so it may be a good idea to cache information. (For example, if you want to display the weather from a weather website, don't make your `bash` prompt go out and retrieve the webpage every time the prompt is displayed!)

Comment: As a sidenote, timestamped `bash` prompts are good as a poor man's `time` for timing the wall-clock time spent executing shell commands. (`time` is more accurate, of course, but I never remember to use it until I've already run the command.)

Comment: Thanks! I was originally thinking of modifying an existing Python script to run in the background, but if I implement it in shellscript (it's a very simple script, like `matt daemon`) I can set it as the `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Great idea!

Comment: Yeah, i was about to write this answer. Just make a "client" to poll the daemon and let the users who want the info add this command to PS1.

Comment: I just got that pun. Oh, god.

Answer (score 2):

A daemon process, by definition should run in the background. Therefore it should write to a log file.

So either you redirect it's output to a logfile (shell redirect or hand it over to some sys logging daemon) or you make it write to a logfile in the python code.

Update:

```
man write
man wall
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/write, http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall

Comment: Which is to say: You told it to write to `sys.stdout`, the standard output device (i.e. your terminal), so that's exactly what it's doing. Tell it to write to a file instead.

Comment: This is very true. I updated my question with clarification on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, `notify-send` might be a nice way to display instant notifications (either via `exec` or via DBus).

Answer (score 2):

It probably is best practice to write to a log file for daemons. But could you not write to stderr and have the behavior desired above with inter-woven lines?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ***logging*** library (part of the standard library). This can be made to route debug and runtime data either to the console or a file (or anywhere for that matter) depending on the state of the system.
It provides several log facilities, e.g. error, debug, info.  Each can be configured differently.

[See documentation on logging - link](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```